# Spring Batch - Re-triggering Service Activator

Tags: java, spring-batch

We have a Spring Batch application that runs in Master-Slave mode. At the master's end there is a Reader which queries the source database and does some processing on the records before it pushes the records into an intermediate table.

While this happens, the master also launches the slaves in parallel. These slaves read the records from the intermediate table that are subject to their partition and start processing them simultaneously, there are 5 slaves that have a distinct partition of records in the intermediate table to deal with.

The Master and Slaves run in different JVMs.

The master uses MessageChannelPartitionHandler to communicate with the slaves. At the slave's end, there is a Service Activator that triggers the step for reading and processing the records from the intermediate table. The Service Activation happens when a partition message arrives in the designated channel. Once completed, each slave acknowledge back to the master through the reply channel.

Suppose, if there has to be some issue at the Master's end while pulling records from the source database or if there is some network delay while inserting the records into the intermediate table. The slaves do not see any new records for their partition, so their readers get closed automatically and they prematurely start sending out replies to the master.

However, the process at the master's end is not fully completed yet. After the slave steps are completed there can be some more new records in the intermediate table. When this situation happens, all these spilled over records have to processed only during the next Job run.

Is there a way to trigger the Service Activation again on the slaves from the master when this situation happens? In other words, can we enforce the slaves to wait till the master's processing is fully completed and all the records are available in the intermediate table, before they send out the reply messages to the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the slave steps are completed there can be some more new records in the intermediate table

Batch processing is about processing *fixed* data sets. If the data source is moving, it becomes stream processing. Assigning a fixed data set for a job is what enables restartability.

According to your design, partitions are not fixed. So you need to make sure each slave processes a fixed set of records or use a streaming solution instead.

Comment: Sorry!, One Job execution will only be against a fixed data set. The Job comprises of 2 Steps. The 1st Step pulls data from the source and pushes into an intermediate table after minor processing. The 2nd step is the Master which starts 5 slaves and waits for them to complete. These 2 steps are executed in parallel, i,e., the slaves start their processing while the 1st Step is still executing, this means slaves start processing even before their partition is fully populated in the intermediate table. So, they also have the risk of getting completed before their partition is fully populated.

Comment: From the worker point of view, the partition is still a moving target. When the worker is started, its reader has already opened a cursor on the table, but records can be added after that. You issue is a design issue, not an implementation issue. The step that fixes the data in an intermediate table should be executed before starting workers, not in parallel with them.